# Rails ActiveRecord Callbacks: Update if Exists, Create if Doesn't Exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rails-activerecord

After combing through the documentation I am having a difficult time understand what callback I should be using.

pseudo code:

*if child_id and outage_id don't exist*

*create a relationship (INSERT statement)*

*if outage_id is changed*

*modify relationship (UPDATE statement)*

These inserts and updates are handled via `collection_check_boxes`

There are 3 models. Relationship, Outage, and Child.

```
class Outage < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :children, through: :relationships
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
end


class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :outage
  belongs_to :child

  validate :check_if_exists, if: :outage_id_changed?

  private

  def check_if_exists
    Relationship.where(child_id: self.child_id).update_all(outage_id: self.outage_id)
  end
end
```

The issue I'm facing now is that an `UPDATE` always occurs right before the `INSERT`, no matter what. An `UPDATE` should only occur if the record exists and the `outage_id` is changed.

Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong here would be appreciated.

Comment: instead of a validation have a look at the `after_save` hook there you can access `saved_changes` on the record and build your logic on that by comparing with the new attributes

Comment: Thank you @neongrau, will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
    before_update :check_if_exists, if: :outage_id_changed?

    private
    def check_if_exists
       # Your logic
    end
end
```

**Note:** In your code check_if_exists will run on create also, since `outage_id` is changing from `nil` to `<some_id>` during create

However using `before_update` will make sure that its run only on update

Also note that you're using `update_all` which results in a direct db query and is not wrapped in transaction. Meaning, if at all update fails, changes made via update_all will not be rolled back

Comment: Good point on `nil`. However, the `UPDATE` action isn't  being recognized: it's always an insert unless I force the issue with `update_all`. So everytime I go to use `collection_check_boxes`, it always views it as an `INSERT`. Repo: https://github.com/ornerymoose/TestAppForStackOverflow